# JPA Many To Many remove entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, dao

I use Hibernate (via **JPA**). There is a method to remove an entity:

```
    public void delete(final ID id) {    entityManager.createQuery(String.format("delete from %s e where e.id = :id", entityClass.getSimpleName()))
.setParameter("id", id).executeUpdate();
    }
```

I remove the entity (with many2many relation):

Hibernate logs:

```
Hibernate: delete from author_to_book where (author_id) in (select id from author where id=?)
Hibernate: delete from author where id=?
```

Who is responsible for removing associations from the binding table? After all, my code specifies the removal from the main table only. 
**How it works?**

Mapping:

```
@Entity
public class Author extends BaseEntity implements IAuthor {

@Column
private String name;

@JoinTable(name = "author_to_book",
        joinColumns =  {@JoinColumn(name = "author_id")} ,
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "book_id")}
)
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = Book.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@OrderBy("title ASC")
private Set<IBook> books = new HashSet<>();
```

**Book** entity does not have a mapping to **Author** entity

Comment: Why remove entities using a query and ignore `em.remove`?? Kinda beats the point of using a persistence API ...

Comment: I answered below.
I really don't understand how it works (em.remove -> via Hibernate implementation). 
Therefore, I asked the question about deleting entities.

Comment: If you dont understand then you read the documentation of your JPA provider. `em.remove` will handle all relationships, and bulk delete query will not (developer takes responsibility). But that is all in the JPA spec, so suggest that you read up on it

Answer (score -1):

Using string to construct a Query SQL is not a good idea for JPA. JPQL or Criteria API should be used. Usually the owning side of an association is responsible for removing rows from join table. For bi-directional relations, the rows in join tables can be deleted from the other side too. It really depends on JPA implementation. As far as I know, **CMobileCom JPA** can manage join tables from both sides.

Disclaimer: I am a developer of [CMobileCom JPA](http://cmobilecom.com), a light-weight JPA implementation for both Android and Java JDBC.

Comment: This is the reason why I use JPQL:
https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/avoid-cascadetype-delete-many-assocations/
If I'm wrong, I'm waiting for comments :)

Comment: It is not very efficient code: "String.format("delete from %s e where e.id = :id", entityClass.getSimpleName())". It is better to directly use "delect from EntityTypeName e where e.id=:id".